# ¿Se puede cambiar los elementos de un borderpane en función de una opción seleccionada?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, javafx11

Estoy haciendo un app para reservar pistas de tenis y me gustaria que en función de lo que se clique se muestre una información u otra sin abrir una nueva ventana. Aquí tengo el menú principal:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces lo que me gustaría sería que si se clica en "Mis reservas", la parte derecha desaparece y deja ver otras cosas y así con cada uno de los botones. He intentado hacerlo invisibilizando los elementos, pero entonces no puedo colocar otros en los mismos lugares. Dejo aquí el grafo de escena por si ayuda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Un saludo.

Comment: Sí se puede . hay que cambiar los hijos del nodo padre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TE sugiero que lo hagas por parte.
El lado izquierdo lo usas para las opciones que muestras pero del lado derecho puedes agregar un ScrollPane.
Luego sobre cada boton como tienes asociada una accion o evento, insertas el FXML dentro del ScrollPane. Cada FXML debe tener su propio controlador para que sea independiente. lo creas normalmente en el scenebuilder pero en el momento de instanciarlo lo colocas dentro de una variable tipo Parent y luego al ScrollPane se lo agregas como un child.

```
    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    Parent interfazDeInteres = ventanasService.cargadorFXML("interfazX.fxml"); // esto es un metodo solo para cargar el fxml
    scrollPane.setContent(interfazDeInteres);
```

REFERENCIA
[Informacion de metodos utiles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/595096/c%C3%B3mo-cambio-la-acci%C3%B3n-de-un-bot%C3%B3n-en-javafx-sin-cambiar-de-escena/605994?noredirect=1#comment1069551_605994)